# Using RallyDev - how do I email a defect record to another user?

Tags: email

We are using Rally Dev - an AGILE management tool. When I raise a defect, I can set an auto trigger to notify the recipient that a defect has been raised.
If, however, I wish to send the defect to another user, as a one off request, how can I do this?

Thanks,
Jamie